# Syncronizing files with AJA Ki Pro using Python

Tags: python, curl

We have an AJA Ki Pro recorder at another location and I a need to created an automated system that pulls the recorded files over to my editing studio.  So far I have successfully been able to pull recordings using a python script run via an Applescript through Automator.  I than can trigger the application from iCal.  Basically my script involves setting the "MediaState" parameter on my recorder to "Data" (value=1) so I can pull files, comparing the files on the recorder to my local files (it only downloads what I dont already have locally), and then setting the "MediaState" property back to "Rec" (value=0) so the recorder is ready to go again.

Here are the 2 problems I have been unable to resolve so far.  Bear with me, I have about 2 days worth of experience with Python :)  It seems that I have somehow created a loop where it constantly says "Looking for new clips" and "No new clips found". Ideally I would like to have the script terminate if no new clips are found.  I would also like to set this up so that when it finishes a download through cURL, it automatically sets my "MediaState" back to value=0 and ends the script.  Here is my code so far:

```
# This script polls the unit downloads any new clips it hasn't already downloaded to the current directory 

# Arguments:  hostname or IP address of Ki Pro unit

import urllib, sys, string, os, posix, time

def is_download_allowed(address):
    f = urllib.urlopen("http://"+address+"/config?action=get&paramid=eParamID_MediaState")
    response = f.read()
    if (response.find('"value":"1"') > -1):
        return True
    f = urllib.urlopen("http://"+address+"/config?action=set&paramid=eParamID_MediaState&value=1")

def download_clip(clip):
    url = "http://" + address + "/media/" + clip
    print url
    posix.system("curl --output " + clip + " " + url);

def download_clips(response):
    values = response.split(":")
    i = 0
    for word in values:
        i += 1
        if(word.find('clipname') > -1):
            clip = values[i].split(',')[0].translate(string.maketrans("",""), '[]{} \,\"\" ')
            if not os.path.exists(clip):
                print "Downloading clip: " + clip
                download_clip(clip)
        else:
            f = urllib.urlopen("http://"+address+"/config?action=set&paramid=eParamID_MediaState&value=0")
            print "No new clips found"

address = sys.argv[1]

while 1:
    if (is_download_allowed(address)):
        print "Looking for new clips"
        f = urllib.urlopen("http://"+address+"/clips")
        response = f.read()
        download_clips(response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `download_clips` function is looping through the clip names, why you need that infinite `while 1` loop? I think it is not necessary. Just remove it and dedent the block.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Making those edits also cause the rest of my script to execute correctly, which solved my other problem.  Thanks for helping a new guy out!